# Why generic type inference doesn't work in that case?

Tags: c#, linq, type-inference

When trying to compile the following code in LINQPad :

```
void Main()
{
    DriveInfo.GetDrives().Select(GetProviderName).Dump();
}

static string GetProviderName(DriveInfo drive)
{
    // some irrelevant WMI code...
}
```

I get the following error :

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)'  cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

If I use a lambda like `d => GetProviderName(d)` instead of a method group, it works fine... I'm quite surprised, because I was sure the compiler would be able to infer the type from the method group. There is no other `GetProviderName` method in scope, and the input and output types are clearly defined, so it should be implicitly convertible to a `Func<DriveInfo, string>`... shouldn't it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a limitation in the compiler that was fixed in C# 4.0

Comment: Ah, I *knew* I had seen it working before... the test above was done in C# 3.0. Do you have any reference link about that ?